# How can I insert Rdoc comments in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine, rdoc

When I used Visual Studio I was used to inserting XML comments with just a few key presses at the beginning of the method definition (I think /// but it's been a while). Is there a way to insert an RDoc comment before a method inside of RubyMine out of the box? If so what is the keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a similar problem, and the default `alt enter` way is not very good. You have to `alt enter` many times, and the generated type is always `Object`.

So I write a plugin to do this trick,

[image: example]

And I have uploaded the plugin to JetBrains (Plugin Repository), you can search `ruby-doc-adder` to download and use it.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9904-ruby-doc-adder.

Also see the [readme](https://github.com/aristotll/RubyDocAdder) for usages.

Comment: Is this RubyMine plugin still being actively supported or developed? Plugin version 0.0.4 is not working in RubyMine v 2019.3